# Is there a way to solve this integral on the sphere explicitly?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis, integration, harmonic-analysis, singularity-theory

Let $k_{j}\in {\mathbb{Z}}^{+}$ and $\,a_{j}\in \,]0,1[$, be such that
$k_{j}\,a_{j}<1$, $j=1,\cdots,n$. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow [0,\infty[$ be defined by the integral

$$f(y):=\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} \,\prod_{j=1}^{n}
|\omega^{k_{j}}_{j}-y_{j}|^{-a_{j}}d\sigma(\omega),$$
where $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ is the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $\sigma$ is the surface measure on the sphere induced by Lebesgue measure. Is there a way to compute $f$ explicitly ?

I stumbled upon this integral in the context of restriction theory. I don't think this integral is known even when $k_{j}=1$ for all $j$.

Comment: I would start with $|t|^{-a}=C(a)\cdot \int_{0}^\infty (e^{itx}+e^{-itx})x^{a-1}dx$ for $t=w_j^{k_j}-y_j$ and $a=a_j$. But unlikely that there exists something fascinating.

Comment: If $k_j a_j>1$ for some $j$, the integral will diverge on the intersection of the hyperplane $y_j=0$ with the sphere.

Comment: @Bazin I added the integrability restriction to the question. Thanks